# RAM upgrade for ASUS Sabertooth X58 motherboard

Tags: memory

I want to upgrade my home rig with more memory, but I don't know which RAM chips I should buy. I currently have 6GB, I need more to be able to run VMs.

I am considering buying Kingston HyperX Red Fury 16GB RAM modules, a kit of 2x 8GB DDR3 1866Mhz CL10. These are "DDR3" but I am not sure if it's compatible with my rig. **How can I tell**?

This is my Motherboard:

[image]

and the CPU:

[image]

and the RAM:

[image]

Comment: You don't want to add two sticks to a triple channel system, you want to add three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASUS Sabertooth X58 motherboard only supports a maximum of 24gb RAM - Since this has 6 DIMM slots, you are looking at a Max of 4gb per DIMM - With that being said, the RAM you are looking to buy, 16gb HpyerX Red Fury 16gb (2x8gb) will not work -

Additionally, your Motherboard support Triple-Channel Memory - Since this is DDR3, you can use Dual-Channel Memory, but it will run in Dual-Channel mode -

If you are looking to upgrade your Memory, it is my Suggestion to look at getting 12gb, or even topping out at 24gb, especially if your main goal is to be able to run more VM's - And when searching for RAM, try and buy Triple-Channel, as this will run a bit smoother

Here is a link to the Specifications of your Motherboard:
https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/SABERTOOTH_X58/specifications/

Hopefully this help

Comment: Any idea what "Mhz" my RAM is running at? I googled `tripple channel ddr3 ram` and found a company called `corsair`. But they offer `1600MHz`, `2000MHz` & `333MHz` in `12GB` config which is within my price range. But which "MHz" should I get?

Comment: @Latheesan Ideally, 1066MHz or higher, CL8 or lower.

Comment: @Latheesan as David said, your board will function with RAM at the following speeds, 1866/1800/1600/1333/1066 - As long as you find Triple-Channel with any of those speeds, you will be fine