# 8GB RAM with ASUS Sabertooth X58

Tags: memory

Can a 8GB RAM in one single port be used with ASUS Sabertooth X58 motherboard? We are having problems with our Motherboard, and need an answer to the above to resolve it.

Comment: Have you looked it up in the manual? Such information is usually in them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RAM upgrade for ASUS Sabertooth X58 motherboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1034873/ram-upgrade-for-asus-sabertooth-x58-motherboard)

Comment: But according to the specs I saw at ASUS website and a [quick search](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/ram-compatibility-x58-mobo.3429589/) tells that you could only have 4GB sticks (in triple channel: 3x4GB or 6x4GB for optimal performance).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes it does support 8GB sticks and up to 48 GB RAM on asus sabertooth x58 with in my case Bloomfield i7 950.

Long answer:
Just to be specific yes the manual states 24GB and 4GB sticks but that is because 8GB were not in wide circulation at the time. Memory installed should be in sets of 3 as triple channel (in very specific slots).

Achieving 24GB with 3 x 8GB sticks is the easiest thing to do achieving decent memory speeds/timings.
I'm upgraded recently (last 4 months) using this quad kit (you won't find a triple kit these days)
32GB (4x8GB) Corsair DDR3 Vengeance Low Profile Jet Black, PC3-12800 (1600), Non-ECC, CAS 10-10-10-27, XMP, 1.5V

One 8GB is not used. Ignore the SPD values they did not match the tested timing values written on the product for some reason. Works stably at 1600Mhz. Passed days of memtest and GSAT.

48GB is more tricky (6 x 8GB sticks) . You can't do this at higher speeds. You WILL need to tweak voltages and test a lot to get it stable. I would not recommend it unless you had a pressing reason to do so.

Type of memory used is key. Not so much speed/ timings but to do with the density/amount of memory chips on each stick.

Before any upgrade make sure you have a test setup prepared BEFORE you make any changes.

Hope this helps another someone else googling.

My X58 system with more RAM, a SSD, new GPU will last for many years to come.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an old posting, some may want to keep their solid PCs alive.

So I confirm that the ASUS Sabertooth X58 with an Intel Core i7-950 can take RAM modules of 8GB each with ease.

My setup now is 32GB RAM using these sticks:

Corsair Vengeance LP DIMM Kit 32GB, DDR3-1600, CL9-10-9-27
(CML32GX3M4A1600C10)

All four modules are installed in a Triple Channel mode and working well.
Tested with Memtest86 v4.3.7

Here is the setup:
[ASUS Sabertooth X58 i7 950 Triple Channel configuration with 32GB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z5Ky.png)